# Trying to train a ParlAI chatbot model. ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, chatbot, parlai

I seem to be getting this error:

```
      File "examples/train_model.py", line 12, in <module>
        from parlai.scripts.train_model import TrainLoop, setup_args
      File "c:\users\dean\pycharmprojects\parlii\~\parlai\parlai\scripts\train_model.py", line 32, in <module>
        from parlai.core.metrics import Metric
      File "c:\users\dean\pycharmprojects\parlii\~\parlai\parlai\core\metrics.py", line 20, in <module>
        import torch
      File "C:\Users\Dean\PycharmProjects\parlii\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
        from torch._C import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

When trying to run this line: 
`python examples/train_model.py -t self_feeding:dialog --model projects.self_feeding.self_feeding_agent:SelfFeedingAgent --model-file /tmp/mymodel1 -bs 128`

I've tried `pip install protobuf==3.6.0` and it still doesn't work. Anyone got any ideas?